# This script keeps crashing

Tags: 2d, python, arcade

I'm using the arcade library, and this script keeps crashing. I think it's my function but idk. Definitely the script, I've run it from two IDEs and the file explorer and every time it shows a black screen and then after a second says "not responding". Full script below.

```
import os
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 2000
arcade.open_window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Asteroids.py.gg.bozo.gitgud")
arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.BLACK)
arcade.start_render()
def loadKraft(x, y):
    arcade.draw_line(x, y + 25, x - 14, y - 18, arcade.color.RED, 6)
    arcade.draw_line(x, y + 25, x + 14, y - 18, arcade.color.RED, 6)
    arcade.draw_line(x - 14, y - 18, x, y - 12, arcade.color.RED, 6)
    arcade.draw_line(x + 14, y - 18, x, y - 12, arcade.color.RED, 6)
loadKraft(0, -59)
arcade.finish_render()
arcade.pause(60)
```

Comment: Have you tried to identify which line is the culprit?

Comment: @Vaillancourt looks like the arcade wait command, the last line there, is triggering the windows "unresponsive" thing. Any way I can get the script to keep displaying the render without making it seem unresponsive?

Comment: Why do you have `arcade.pause(60)` there at all? [Example Arcade projects I can find do not include this line](https://realpython.com/arcade-python-game-framework/), and [the documentation says this would halt your game for a solid 60 seconds](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/api/window.html#arcade.pause), naturally making it unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

> keeps crashing

Technically, nope.

> every time it shows a black screen and then after a second says "not responding"

Your script is technically *freezing* or *stalling*.

> it shows a black scree

In this piece of code

```
def loadKraft(x, y):
    arcade.draw_line(x, y + 25, x - 14, y - 18, arcade.color.RED, 6)
    arcade.draw_line(x, y + 25, x + 14, y - 18, arcade.color.RED, 6)
    arcade.draw_line(x - 14, y - 18, x, y - 12, arcade.color.RED, 6)
    arcade.draw_line(x + 14, y - 18, x, y - 12, arcade.color.RED, 6)
```

try to replace x and y with the values you supply here:

```
loadKraft(0, -59)
```

You'll realize that the `y` coordinates you supply are always negative. This likely means that you try to draw outside your viewport and so, well, you don't see it.

To fix this, try to draw everything using positive coordinates.

> `arcade.pause(60)`

This will pause your game for 60 *seconds*. I don't know what is the intention here, but if you started your script and did not wait those 60 seconds, it likely means that you ask your game to *freeze* during this period of time until it finishes.

So to fix this issue, try to make it pause for a smaller amount of time.

> Any way I can get the script to keep displaying the render without making it seem unresponsive?

I think what you're missing, from looking at examples (I haven't tried it myself), is to call this

```
arcade.run()
```

instead of

```
arcade.pause(60)
```